# No MaterialCardView background in darkview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview, material-components-android

I have recently moved from `material-1.0` to `1.2` (the problem is in place with 1.1 too!)
Now, every thing is ok in `Light` view, but in `Dark` view, there is no card background. See the attached pictures to see what I mean.
[image: Dark View]
[image: Light View]

I am attaching my java and xml files so that you can kindly check.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

  private Context mContext;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
      AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
    } else {
      AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO_BATTERY);
    }
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    String theme = sharedPref.getString("theme", "Default");
//    Toast.makeText(this, theme, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (theme.equals("Dark")) {
      AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    } else if (theme.equals("Light")) {
      AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
    } else {
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
      } else {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO_BATTERY);
      }
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContext = getApplicationContext();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

//    Navigation Drawer
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
        R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    if (drawer != null) {
      drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    }
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    if (navigationView != null) {
      navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
  }


  @Override
  public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.nav_manage:
        // Handle the tools action (for now display a toast).
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        Intent intentSetting = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intentSetting);
        return true;
      case R.id.about_phocast:
        // Handle the share action (for now display a toast).
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://rudrab.github.io/thePhocast")));
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
//        displayToast(getString(R.string.chose_share));
        return true;
      default:
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

**appbar_main.xml**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
      android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
      android:title="@string/app_name" />

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_margin="8dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="-2dp"
      android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
      android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight"
      app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
      app:cardElevation="4dp">

      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="80dp"
          android:contentDescription="@string/cityimg_desc"
          android:scaleType="fitXY"
          app:srcCompat="@drawable/property_image_3" />



          <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/myrect"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingEnd="0dp"
            android:text="@string/location_not_found"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

      </LinearLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
  </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**style.xml=style-night.xml**

```
<resources>

  <!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar" />

</resources>
```

And I cant find out where the error is.

Kindly help/

**Update: after @Soumik and @Gabriele's post**
My updated theme is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
      android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
      android:title="@string/app_name" />

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
      style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_margin="8dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="-2dp"
      app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
      app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
      app:cardElevation="4dp">

      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="80dp"
          android:contentDescription="@string/cityimg_desc"
          android:scaleType="fitXY"
          app:srcCompat="@drawable/property_image_3" />


        <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@drawable/myrect"
          android:elevation="8dp"
          android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingEnd="0dp"
          android:text="@string/location_not_found"
          android:textColor="#ffffff"
          android:textSize="20sp" />

      </LinearLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
  </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

The result of the changed xml file is updated, and a screenshot is added. Kindly check.

Comment: activity_main is missing. Kindly edit your question

Comment: Actually, I thought that is not required, the cardView is in app_bar_main, which is given. Do you really think that is required? I am if put that, the lenth of the question will be repulsively big

Comment: The use of `android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight"` in the `MaterialCardView` doesn't make sense. Also remove `android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"` and use `app:cardBackgroundColor`. It should be enough to change the background color in your card.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti: I am talking about the Teal color (my `colorPrimary`, which is there in the Light version (bottom), but not in the dark (top)) around the card. I will do things and post the update

Comment: @BaRud In any case the teal color is not related to the Card. The default background color of the card is based on **`colorSurface`** or overridden by `cardBackgroundColor` attribute. In the dark mode there is an [**elevation overlay**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Dark.md#elevation-overlays) placed on the top of the background color

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti: I checked the linked material, on elevation overlay, and it seems I can't do anything about that. Everything was ok with AppCompat and material 1.0 library. Can you see(with the new picture and layout added) if I am missing something, or this is how it is supposed to be?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti: Problem solved. had to put `backgroundcolor` in `appoverlay`. But as you said, theme in `cardview` does not make any sense, so should i put `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight` in style only?

Comment: `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight` is the app theme. You can use in a view (for example `CardView`) the `android:theme` attribute to override the colors defined in the app theme only for the specific view without changing the global theme. The style attribute is different. You can use it to extend or override the default style used by the view. The `MaterialCardView` uses the [`Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.1.0/lib/java/com/google/android/material/card/res/values/styles.xml#L21) style as default.

Answer (score -1):

Use

> ```
>     app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
> ```
>
> instead of
>
> ```
>     android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
> ```

Comment: That will change the background of the card itself (i.e., textview part's background), not the dark region around the card.

Comment: @BaRud It is not clear what you are asking. `android:background` in a cardView is wrong.

Comment: As your Title was **No MaterialCardView background in darkview** i thought you need to change the card background. Anyway, you can change the background of your parent layout in according to your theme. ie: `if(theme.equals("Dark)) { parent_layout.setBackground("your bg") }`